# SceneKit – How to remove artifacts from imported Maya scene?

Tags: animation, scenekit, maya

I want to have a moving 3D Animated Flag in SceneKit where I can change the Flag-Textures to different countries.

My current solution is the following:

I imported the flag scene from Maya to SceneKit in the DAE format. The DAE consists of a Plane which has joints attached to it. It is converted from an original nCloth movement using [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fUpTu-uMFRo) method.

My Problem is now, that the flag has artifacts in it - especially visible in the shadow areas:

[image: flag with poor quality]

I can't figure out if this artifacts come from the number of faces in the plane or the number of joints on the plane or the smoothing out of the movement itself.

My thoughts:

- Maybe increasing the amount of joints to smooth out the movement
  would be successful, but my problem is that the exported DAE has
  already 50 MB and I don't want to increase these, because of storage
  of the endusers-device. At the moment there ~450 jointpositions * 500     keyframes = 50MB
- I tried already subdividing the flag in maya, but with the "Smooth
  Bind Tool" which I have to apply, the result is poorer than before. I
  expect because the amount of joints stays equal and the subdivided
  areas don't get more "Movement-Information".
- I tried also subdivision in SceneKit directly, but without an better
  result.
- In Mayas Weight Paint Tool, there are the same bad geometries visible
  when I select a joint. However I am not successful in smoothing out
  these sharp lines of the weights between the corners of the quads:

[image: jointweights]

Has anyone an Idea how to clean out the artifacts or helpful advices?

Are there any recommendations for a complete other solution?

I don't want to use third party game engines for that. I found already examples for such an simulation for Open GL, but I don't want to teach myself the next few month (years..?) how to programm an realistic Cloth simulation. Blender has also an cloth-Simulator, but I can't use the code of blender without porting it to swift (I am not capable of that either..)

### Edit:

No Luck in enabling/disabling litPerPixel on Material, although a slightly bit better:

```
material.litPerPixel = true
```

[image: screenshot_litPerPixel_true]

```
material.litPerPixel = false
```

[image: screenshot_litPerPixel_false]

Comment: Looking at the screenshot it looks like the lighting is done per vertex and not per fragment. Per fragment should be the default. Did you change material.litPerPixel? (or maybe maya exported it like that). Can you try to force material.litPerPixel = YES; ?

Comment: was already set.. unfortunately very little effect. Artifacts still here; Updated Question

Answer (score 1):

For resolving this issue, or in other words, for getting rid of these nasty artifacts on your model, the most robust and simple approach is to increase a poly resolution. For this just apply a `Smooth` command to polygonal geometry before using it as `nCloth` object.

You can export your model as `.usd` format from Maya 2020 / 2022 using [Maya USD plugin](https://github.com/Autodesk/maya-usd/releases) (and then convert it as `.usdz` using USDPython tools) for **SceneKit** and **RealityKit** or as `.dae` file format for **SceneKit** framework. Optimal output poly-res for your flag must be not greater than 10K polygons.